# Pass custom debug information to Microsoft bot framework emulator

Tags: c#, debugging, botframework, chatbot

I am developing a bot based on a .NET Bot Builder SDK.

Is it possible for a bot to pass some debug information together with the message, so I can see it in the *Details* section of the Bot Framework Chanel Emulator when the message is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great Question.  Yes, it is entirely possible.  You can use the `ChannelData` property of your activity you are responding with.  The data entered into the `ChannelData` property must be valid JSON For example:

```
var reply = activity.CreateReply("test");
string json = @"{
    CustomField1: 'Field one value',
    CustomField2Array: [
        'First Element',
        'Second Element'
        ]
    }";


reply.ChannelData = JObject.Parse(json);
await context.PostAsync(reply);
```

In the emulator this will appear as:

```
"channelData": {
    "CustomField1": "Field one value",
    "CustomField2Array": [
      "First Element",
      "Second Element"
    ]
  }
```