# Custom debug logging with Microsoft Bot Framework Emulator v4

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

Is it possible to add custom debug logs to a message with [Microsoft Bot Framework Emulator v4](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator) ?

You can view some logging in the inspector:
[image]

I have tried a solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001873/pass-custom-debug-information-to-microsoft-bot-framework-emulator), this is a solution for Bot Framework V3

```
var reply = activity.CreateReply("test");
string json = @"{
    CustomField1: 'Field one value',
    CustomField2Array: [
        'First Element',
        'Second Element'
        ]
    }";


reply.ChannelData = JObject.Parse(json);
await context.PostAsync(reply);
```

But this doesn't work for a Dialog in Bot Framework V4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ChannelData** can still be set within a Bot Builder V4 dialog and viewed with the V4 Emulator:

```
 var reply = step.Context.Activity.CreateReply();

 string json = @"{
     CustomField1: 'Field one value',
     CustomField2Array: [
         'First Element',
         'Second Element'
                        ]
     }";

  reply.ChannelData = JObject.Parse(json);
```

[image]